# My Wss 3.0 web application only authenticates with basic authentication. HELP!

Tags: wss-3.0, windows-server, windows-authentication

I just installed fresh install of windows server 2008 R2. Then I installed wss 3.0 64 bit in the server. Install finished sucessfully, i installed standalone version with Windows Internal  Database. Then  i created a web application, then  Top Level Site collection with Team Site Template asssigned my account as Site Collection Admin.

It completed sucessfully, then i went in and made changes in host file to host it from local host. I ran iisreset after that, then went in tried to open the site, it gave me windows authentication.

So now it didnt let me in, then i went to iis and disabled windows auth and enabled basic it finally let me in and can browse the site.

I dont know why is it doing this, any insights would be greatly appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: guessing you are facing a http 401.1 or 401.2 error ? please check in the iis logs (search for status and substatus).

Comment: Hello Steve thank you for you reply, but i dont see any error code in browser or in iis log files. its weird that my authentication works fine in central admin.

Comment: I bet your central admin is accessed using `http://servername:port`, while your app is accessed using a custom host header (`http://www.corp.com/`). am I right ?

Comment: Yeah i am using custom host header http://abc in port 80

Comment: I'm still believing you have either a 401.1 or 401.2 error in IIS log file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to use custom host headers with windows authentication, you have to disable loopback check or whitelist the host names.

Follow this [Microsoft KB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896861).

I highly advise you to use the second method (white list) on production servers, as the first method shut down a security mechanism.

Comment: Applying DisableLoopbackCheck worked !!! thank you.